# How to read environments file from external library?

Tags: angular

I'm creating a npm package for my projects. I always use the same structure with Angular4 for my frontend projects so I decided to make my life easier by centralizing those components/behaviors. The problem is, one of the services I'd like to add to this lib is the request service. A service I created to centralize all my REST requests. Inside this service I read the `environments` file.

My question is: How do I read the `environments` file of the app my lib is installed on?

Since my lib won't have such a file, is there a way to retrieve that information? I thought about using an abstract class and inheriting it inside my app, but `environments` is a simple constant...

Is there a way to do that? This is hindering my progress with this library...

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue, the best I have come up with is having the functions in the service accept the variables from the environment files as inputs and passing them in through the component. There has to be a better way though

Edit: here is the better way: [How can an npm package be created that will be able to use a baseUrl from the environment file of whichever project it is imported into?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53565163/9518388)