# How can an npm package be created that will be able to use a baseUrl from the environment file of whichever project it is imported into?

Tags: angular

My company has started a private npm package repository. I am trying to get some of our regularly reused code into packages that can then be installed from the server and imported into projects. For all of our projects we use the environment files with values for the base url of whichever api the project is using. Normally we would import the environment file into the service and use the base url value to execute the calls to the api. With a packaged service we are not able to do this in the same way.

Right now I am working on a login/authorization package. The best I could come up with so far was to:

1. import the environment file into the parent component for the login page
2. then pass the baseUrl value from the environment file to the login screen component (inside the package) using @Input()
3. then have that component pass the baseUrl to the call to the service (inside the package)

Though messy that works okay. The issue comes we also have interceptors that call  the functions in the service and I feel like any solution I was coming up with was super hacky, and I feel like there must be a better way.

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you `import` the modules, you could pass the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar problem. The trick is to have the configuration injected by the declaration of the module to the library. For example, in the library, the module that need the injected config is defined like:

```
export class TestModule {
  static forRoot(moduleConfig: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ...
      providers: [
        { provide: 'testModuleConfig', useValue: moduleConfig }
      ]
    };
  }
```

In the service of the library, to get the config:

```
constructor(
    @Inject('testModuleConfig') private ModuleConfig: any
)
```

And to use it in the application that use the library, you pass the configuration in the `forRoot`:

```
imports: [
    TestModule.forRoot(environment.appconfig),
],
```

Hope this helps.